# Slick carousel code from their website is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel, slick.js

This is the code from slick's website, it doesn't work. is there something here I am missing.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyEddO

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="your-class">
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.your-class').slick({
        setting-name: setting-value
      });
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about it isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `setting-name: setting-value` is what is causing the carousel not to work. If you remove that line (or replace it with supported settings) then the carousel will work.

Updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMpZdM

Comment: thank  you, knew posting it on stackoverflow would get me an answer right away :)